# TypeError: __init_subclass__() takes no keyword arguments

Tags: python, metaclass

I'm trying to create a metaclass but when I assign it to another class I receive the error:

> TypeError: `__init_subclass__()` takes no keyword arguments

But I don't implement any `__init_subclass__`. Why is this function being called?

```py
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)

class MyClass(meta=Meta):
    pass
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change `meta` to `metaclass`. Any keyword arguments passed to the signature of your class are passed to its parent's `__init_subclass__` method. Since you entered `meta` instead of `metaclass` this `meta` kwarg is passed to its parent's (`object`) `__init_subclass__` method:

```py
>>> object.__init_subclass__(meta=5)
TypeError: __init_subclass__() takes no keyword arguments
```

A similar error would be raised if you actually implemented a `__init_subclass__` but made a typo:

```py
class Parent:
  def __init_subclass__(cls, handler=None):
    super().__init_subclass__()
    cls.handler = handler

class CorrectChild(Parent, handler=5):
  pass

class TypoChild(Parent, typo=5):
  # TypeError: __init_subclass__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'typo'
  pass
```

Comment: Good answer - just one correction: the default `__init_subclass__` that is called is `object.__init_subclass__`, not `type.__init_subclass__`: this method is called in the super-classes not on the metaclass. 

Also, it is a good pratice to call `super().__init_subclas__` inside the method, so that your base classes are composable.