# mypy Error: Unexpected keyword argument for "__init_subclass__"

Tags: python, class, mypy

I just started using mypy to lint my code and I found an error I can't understand, that is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63448679).

I understand the question and it's answer, and it works.
Nonetheless,when I split the files and import them I still get the error.
Using the same classes as the answer to the Q:

File `parent.py`

```
class Parent:
  def __init_subclass__(cls, handler=None):
    super().__init_subclass__()
    cls.handler = handler
```

File `child.py`

```
from parent import Parent

class CorrectChild(Parent, handler=5):
{Unexpected keyword argument "handler" for "__init_subclass__" of "object"mypy(error)}
  pass
```

The problem disappears when I put the correctChild inside the parent file, but i don't want to do that, as my actual file is way too long.

Don't know if it is useful, but I'm getting the error in vscode.

Comment: I think this is more a problem *with* `mypy` than a problem found *by* `mypy`; my guess is that something about `__init_subclass__` is a bit *too* dynamic for a static type checker to handle.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in MyPy and most likely unrelated to your code: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/11036

Comment: could you please elaborate? what is the cause? in what version is the bug fixed?